# Pass prop as parameter to method in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component and I pass props into it:

```vue
export default {
    props: [
        "notificationDate",
        "notificationType",
        "notificationMessage",
        "downLoadLink",
        "inProgress",
        "downloadImage",
        "count",
        "name"
    ],
}
```

In my template, i use these props:

```
 <div class="notification">
    <span class="time">{{notificationDate}}</span>
    <p><b>{{notificationType}}:</b> {{notificationMessage}}</p>
```

For one prop, "count", I want to pass it to a method in the click event of a button. I tried this:

```
  <b-button type="is-danger" size="is-small"
            icon-right="delete" @click="deleteNotification(count)")">
    Remove
  </b-button>
```

But in my method, count is undefined:

```
      methods: {
        deleteNotification(count) {
          //count is undefined
        }}
```

How do I pass my prop into my @click method? Thanks

Comment: just @click="deleteNotification(count)" no curlies needed

Comment: methods: {
        deleteNotification(count) {//count is undefined

Comment: this works, i forgot to pass in count to my component from the vue its being crreated in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it like this:

```vue
<b-button 
    type="is-danger" 
    size="is-small"
    icon-right="delete"
    @click="deleteNotification(count)"
>
    Remove
</b-button>
```

Comment: methods: {
        deleteNotification(count) {//count is undefined

Comment: nevermind, this works...i missed one step after making the suggested change